# Securing Web Sockets in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, https, certificate

I’m in the process of securing our REST API endpoints in spring boot.  I have the certificate created and implemented for all our endpoints which is working perfectly with HTTPS.  I now however struggling with web sockets via the same secured port.  Below is the snippet of code I have used to obtain the SSLContext and Rest template.  The method setupStompClient is where I need the help.  How do I set the SSLContect for web sockets?

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   try {
        serverUrl = getUrl();
        certName = getCertName();
        certPassword = getCertPassword();
        restTemplate = getTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(
             new CommunicationErrorHandler(restTemplate.getMessageConverters()));
         if (isWebsocket()) {
            setupStompClient();
         } 
   } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CommunicationException(e.getMessage(), e);
   }    
}
   
private RestTemplate getTemplate() {
              SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();
              SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = 
                  new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
             CloseableHttpClient httpClient =    HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory).build();
             ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = 
                  new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
             RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
             return restTemplate;
}
      
private SSLContext getSSLContext() {
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
         sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
         .loadTrustMaterial(new URL(certName), certPassword.toCharArray()).build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException |      CertificateException | IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sslContext;
}
      
protected void setupStompClient() {
     WebSocketClient simpleWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
     List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
     transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(simpleWebSocketClient));
     SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
 
     stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
     stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[] { 10000, 10000 });
     taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
     taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();
 
     stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
     stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
}
```

this is the error I'm getting due to the fact that I don't have the certificate implemented for the web sockets

```
09:00:09.753 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService
09:00:09.792 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport - Executing SockJS Info request, url=https://localhost:8070/pk-websocket/info
09:00:09.819 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET https://localhost:8070/pk-websocket/info
09:00:10.001 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient - Initial SockJS "Info" request to server failed, url=wss://localhost:8070/pk-websocket
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for https://localhost:8070/pk-websocket/info: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport.executeInfoRequestInternal(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:138)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractXhrTransport.executeInfoRequest(AbstractXhrTransport.java:128)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.getServerInfo(SockJsClient.java:294)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.doHandshake(SockJsClient.java:260)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:270)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:250)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:230)
       at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:214)
       at com.rmbms.business.communication.StompSessionHandler.start(StompSessionHandler.java:45)
       at com.rmbms.test.TestSecureCommunication.startRiskLimitListeners(TestSecureCommunication.java:50)
       at com.rmbms.test.TestSecureCommunication.main(TestSecureCommunication.java:68)
```

Thanks

I have search this site but have not found an answer that works

Comment: You can use ``` before/after the beginning/ending lines to format your code/log.